# How can I get the wifi to work on Ubuntu 15.10 on a MacBook Pro Retina 10.2?

Tags: wireless, 15.10, macbook

I recently decided to give Linux a try and after some research I decided on Ubuntu. I went ahead and installed it on a 16GB flash drive and moved all my schoolwork to another flash drive I had in case I decided to completely switch over and get rid of iOS on my laptop, so for now Ubuntu 15.10 is booting from my flash drive on my MacBook 10.2 and it turns out the wifi adaptor in my laptop isn't functional with Ubuntu right away. I looked up some fixes and tried to do them (I am 99% sure I got it all right) but nothing is working so far and I can't find any other fixes, so I decided to come here for help. Does anyone know how to get the wifi working on Ubuntu 15.10 on a MacBook 10.2? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are one of those who installed any version of Ubuntu on your Macbook Pro and the OS doesn't detect your WiFi, get connected to internet using cable, Bluetooth, etc. and simply run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install -y linux-firmware-nonfree b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
reboot
```

Voila!! Your computer restarts and it should easily detect your WiFi hardware.

Comment: There is no need for `linux-firmware-nonfree`, `b43-fwcutter ` will be installed by itself and this solution works not with all Broadcom devices.